# Can someone explain this proof by case example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't fully understand this example the book gives.  I understand the section where they examine when $x\gt0$ but when $x\lt0$ things get murky for me.

Prove that for every real number $x$, $x\le\lvert x \rvert$.

Comment: If $x$ is negative then $x\lt 0\lt |x|$. More concretely, let $x=-17$. Then $|x|=17$, so certainly $x\lt |x|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 cases: $x < 0$ or $x \ge 0$.

**Case 1: $x \ge 0$**

Now, when $x \ge 0,\ |x| = x$. Since $x \ge x,\ |x| \ge x \implies x \le |x|$.

e.g. when $x = 5,\ |x| = 5.\text{ So}\ 5 \le 5$

**Case 2: $x < 0$**
When $x < 0,\ |x|=-x>0$.

Now, a positive number $-x$ is always greater than a negative number $x$.

Thus, $-x = |x| > x \implies x \le |x|$.

e.g. when $x = -4,\ |x| = 4 \ge -4.$

From 1 and 2, $x \le |x|,\ \forall x \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Ah this makes more sense, I think the book wrote your second line in Case 2 a little differently from what you said, but that makes it pretty clear.

Comment: About why `|x|>x` for `x<0` it can be noted that `x<0, |x|>0 => x<0<|x|`.

Answer (score 3):

The most used definition of $|x|$ is

$$|x|=\max(x,-x)$$
and knowing this it's clear that

$$|x|=\max(x,-x)\ge x$$

Answer (score 0):

$$-1\le|-1|=+1\\+1\le|+1|=+1$$
You can replace $1$ by any (positive) number.